# Morph tweening in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop-effects

How can I create a static image that conveys morphing from one side to another?

E.g., in the following image composited of three shots of the same woman in different positions I want something like a morph trail from one to the other, except that of course it must be blurred or staggered because I want a static, not animated image.

[image]

Comment: I don't know where to start.  Not even sure I'm using the right terminology.

Comment: so you want to show some action in her left arm to be shown as its move so fast?

Comment: I want to keep the left and right shots separated on the page, and a blur connecting the two to convey the action that has occurred.  This is a simple case since the subject hasn't rotated and only the arms have moved.  A more complex but useful one might involve starting with the subject rotated 90 degrees to one side, so we would get the sense that we have panned around while the subject has made some in-place movement.  I believe I've seen effects like this in real-world illustrations and will post examples if I manage to find them....